# Copy file from remote to byte[]

Tags: go, scp

I'm trying to figure out how to implement copying files from remote and get the data `[]byte` from the buffer.

I have succeeded in doing the implementation with the upload by referring to this guide: https://chuacw.ath.cx/development/b/chuacw/archive/2019/02/04/how-the-scp-protocol-works.aspx

Inside the `go func` there's the implementation of the `upload` process of the `SCP` but I have no idea how to change it.

Any advice ?

```
func download(con *ssh.Client, buf bytes.Buffer, path string,) ([]byte,error) {
    //https://chuacw.ath.cx/development/b/chuacw/archive/2019/02/04/how-the-scp-protocol-works.aspx
    session, err := con.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        return nil,err
    }

    buf.WriteString("sudo scp -f " + path + "\n")

    stdin, err := session.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return nil,err
    }
    go func() {
        defer stdin.Close()
        fmt.Fprint(stdin, "C0660 "+strconv.Itoa(len(content))+" file\n")
        stdin.Write(content)
        fmt.Fprint(stdin, "\x00")
    }()

    output, err := session.CombinedOutput("sudo scp -f " + path)
    buf.Write(output)
    if err != nil {
        return nil,&DeployError{
            Err:    err,
            Output: buf.String(),
        }
    }

    session.Close()

    session, err = con.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        return nil,err
    }
    defer session.Close()

    return output,nil
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to manually implement the scp protocol, rather than using an existing library or a more standard protocol?

Comment: It's good to know how to "implement" it

Comment: Do you implement HTTP rather than using an http library? If you're asking for the sake of learning how to implement it, that's fine -- but you need to at least try to implement it and then we can help with problems you may have encountered.

Comment: I have already implemented it for `uploading` as you can see. I don't understand what doe's it matter for the sake of what I'm asking it. It's supposed to work and I'm missing something in the process. I don't want to use any package wahtsoever.

Answer (score 1):

The sink side is significantly more difficult than the source side. Made an example which should get you close to what you want. Note that I have not tested this code, that the error handling is sub optimal and it only supports 1/4th the protocol messages SCP may use. So you will still need to do some work to get it perfect.

With all that said, this is what I came up with:

```golang
func download(con *ssh.Client, path string) ([]byte, error) {
    //https://chuacw.ath.cx/development/b/chuacw/archive/2019/02/04/how-the-scp-protocol-works.aspx
    session, err := con.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer session.Close()

    // Local -> remote
    stdin, err := session.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer stdin.Close()

    // Request a file, note that directories will require different handling
    _, err = stdin.Write([]byte("sudo scp -f " + path + "\n"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Remote -> local
    stdout, err := session.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Make a buffer for the protocol messages
    const megabyte = 1 << 20
    b := make([]byte, megabyte)

    // Offset into the buffer
    off := 0

    var filesize int64

    // SCP may send multiple protocol messages, so keep reading
    for {
        n, err := stdout.Read(b[off:])
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        nl := bytes.Index(b[:off+n], []byte("\n"))
        // If there is no newline in the buffer, we need to read more
        if nl == -1 {
            off = off + n
            continue
        }

        // We read a full message, reset the offset
        off = 0

        // if we did get a new line. We have the full protocol message
        msg := string(b[:nl])

        // Send back 0, which means OK, the SCP source will not send the next message otherwise
        _, err = stdin.Write([]byte("0\n"))
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        // First char is the mode (C=file, D=dir, E=End of dir, T=Time metadata)
        mode := msg[0]
        if mode != 'C' {
            // Ignore other messags for now.
            continue
        }

        // File message = Cmmmm <length> <filename>
        msgParts := strings.Split(msg, " ")
        if len(msgParts) > 1 {
            // Parse the second part <length> as an base 10 integer
            filesize, err = strconv.ParseInt(msgParts[1], 10, 64)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
        }

        // The file message will be followed with binary data containing the file
        break
    }

    // Wrap the stdout reader in a limit reader so we will not read more than the filesize
    fileReader := io.LimitReader(stdout, filesize)
    // Seed the bytes buffer with the existing byte slice, saves additional allocation if file <= 1mb
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(b)

    // Copy the file into the bytes buffer
    _, err = io.Copy(buf, fileReader)
    return buf.Bytes(), err
}
```